# Translate vuejs route paths

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I got this fine idea about translating routes paths, which doesn't sound so clever any more :), once I have encountered a problem. I hope you guys will see/find a solution.

This is my routes.js file, where routes are defined

```
export default [
    {
        path: '/:lang',
        component: {
            template: '<router-view></router-view>'
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                name: 'Home',
                component: load('Home')
            },
            {
                path: translatePath('contact'),
                name: 'Contact',
                component: load('Contact')
            },
            {
                path: translatePath('cookiePolicy'),
                name: 'CookiePolicy',
                component: load('CookiePolicy')
            },
        ]
    },
]

// and my simple function for translating paths
function translatePath(path) {
    let lang = Cookie.get('locale');

    let pathTranslations = {
        en: {
            contact: 'contact',
            cookiePolicy: 'cookie-policy',
        },
        sl: {
            contact: 'kontakt',
            cookiePolicy: 'piskotki',
        }
    };

    return pathTranslations[lang][path];
}
```

And this is my change language functionality in my component

```
setLocale(locale) {
    let selectedLanguage = locale.toLowerCase();
    this.$my.locale.setLocale(selectedLanguage); // update cookie locale
    console.log(this.$route.name);
    this.$router.replace({ name: this.$route.name, params: { lang: selectedLanguage } });
    location.reload();
},
```

The problem is following. When user executes the change language functionality I successfully change lang param, but the `this.$route.name` keeps the same in old language. Is there a way to **"reload"** routes, so there will be new routes paths, which will include proper language?

If you need any additional informations, please let me know and I will provide. Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/
Might help point you in the right direction....

Comment: does the path in `children` need to include the parent's path: `/:lang/`  ??

Comment: @TangYun Currently yes, otherwise it's not working. But I assume, that this is my problem! Didn't find any docs regarding this yet

Comment: @AlexMulchinock I have already played with vue-i18n, but I didn't found a solution how to translate route paths. Thx for suggestion any way!

Comment: @Valor_, checkout https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html

Comment: @TangYun yep, then this is a problem on my part which I need to figure out! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this basic example, you can see the path that change according to the selected language.
This can be improved using some translation plugin like vue-i18n and can also be wrapped into a mixin for more reusability.

```js
const Home = {
  template: '<div>Home</div>'
}
const Contact = {
  template: '<div>CONTACT ==> {{$route.path}}</div>'
}
const Cookie = {
  template: '<div>COOKIE ==> {{$route.path}}</div>'
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
      name: 'home',
      path: '/',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      name: 'contact',
      path: '/:pathTranslation',
      component: Contact
    },
    {
      name: 'cookies',
      path: '/:pathTranslation',
      component: Cookie
    }
  ]
})

new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    lang: 'IT',
    translations: {
      IT: {
        contact: 'Contatti',
        cookies: 'Cookies IT',
      },
      EN: {
        contact: 'Contacts',
        cookies: 'Cookies EN',
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    lang: function(newLang) {
      this.goto(this.$route.name, newLang);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    goto(path, lang=null) {
      this.$router.replace({
        name: path,
        params: {
          pathTranslation: this.translations[lang || this.lang][path]
        }
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select v-model="lang">
    <option value="IT">IT</option>
    <option value="EN">EN</option>
  </select>
  <button @click="goto('contact')">To contact</button>
  <button @click="goto('cookies')">To cookies</button>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```